# How do I view all my weight data in apple health on iOS?

Tags: health.app

Is there a way to show a list of dates and times and weights in the Apple health app on iOS? I don’t want to see it as a graph.

Answer (score 1):

On the weight screen it will show a graph with D, W, M, Y across the top to change the graph time scale for days, weeks, months and years. While you are on this same screen, scroll all the way down to the bottom and there will be a button that says Show All Data. Click on this button and you can view all the records you have entered and also edit them. This applies to iOS 13.6.1.

Posting this answer because my version of Apple Health did not have a health data tab that @anki mentioned in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Choose "show all data" in Health Data tab.

  > [image]
- Export your health data in Today tab > top right corner: human icon > export all data.
- Download your health data from https://privacy.apple.com

Comment: Thanks but I must have a different version because there are only two tabs. Summary and browse. I found what I was looking for by going to the weight graph and scrolling down to the bottom of the screen where a show all data button was hiding.

Comment: I would but health data tab doesn’t exist.

Comment: That'd be good for an answer by you since I don't know what UI you're setting. You can accept that answer then.